# How to set a cookie with CGICC and C++?

Tags: c++, cookies, cgi

I need to set some cookies using C++, but I can't seem to get them to set, and am quite unfamiliar with CGICC so I don't know where I'm going wrong. Here's my login code (I know it's very insecure, this is homework, nothing that will ever be public facing)

```
void login(cgicc::Cgicc formdata, std::vector<User> &users)
{
    bool success = false;
    std::string userName = getValue("username", formdata);
    std::string password = getValue("password", formdata);
    for(auto iter = users.begin(); iter != users.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if(iter->getUsername() == userName && iter->getPassword() == password)
        {
            success = true;
            std::string id = std::to_string(iter->getID());
            std::cout << "<script> alert(\"Login was successful!\"); </script>" << std::endl;
            std::cout << cgicc::HTTPHTMLHeader().setCookie(cgicc::HTTPCookie("username", userName));
            std::cout << cgicc::HTTPHTMLHeader().setCookie(cgicc::HTTPCookie("userID", id));
        }
    }
    if(!success)
        std::cout << "<script> alert(\"Failed to login. Check your credentials and try again\");</script>"<<std::endl;
}
```

All the other code has been verified to be working correctly, just the cookie setting code is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this as an example:

```
std::cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n";
std::cout << "Set-Cookie:count=2;\n";
std::cout << "Set-Cookie:user=tizio;\n";
std::cout << "Set-Cookie:password=profdfosfiotjrejiod;\n\n"
```

these lines must be the first of the html page